# defining sym outside the function MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, symbolic-math

I have a 4 by 3 matrix ('mymatrix'). myfunc inputs 'mymatrix' and outputs 'result'. I am using myfunc in a loop (for 17280 times) in my script. So, each time, it redefines syms x y z t. Is there a way to take 'syms x y z t' outside myfunc. It takes 0.004 second to initialize in each time.

```
function result = myfunc(mymatrix)

tic
syms x y z t
toc

f = 3*x+5*y-6*z+7;
eqn = subs(f,{x,y,z},{mymatrix(:,1)*t,mymatrix(:,2)*t,mymatrix(:,3)*t});

for ii = 1:4
    result(ii,1) = solve(eq(ii))
end
```

PS: I also tried to vectorize for loop but could not succeed. If you can, I will be glad.

Comment: You said you are calling this function `17280` times. And since the input to this function is `mymatrix`, I am assuming that matrix is changing across these iterations in some sort of loop. So, here's my question - Do you have access to all these `17280` sets of data before starting that loop of `for iterations = 1:17280` ?

Comment: Also, would it be okay to obtain `result` as a numeric array or do you absolutely need a sym variable as output?

Comment: What is `class(mymatrix)`? Is it numeric or symbolic?

Comment: 'mymatrix' is the output of another function and it is not known before the loop starts. 
    'mymatrix' is numeric.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the symbolic variables to be persistent during the execution:

```
function result = myfunc(mymatrix)

    persistent x y z t
    if isempty(x)
        syms x y z t
    end
    ...
end
```

This results in about a 10% decrease in execution time on my machine (0.65-ish to 0.59-ish from the profiler).

However, as @Divakar pointed out in the comments, since `results` is numeric and not symbolic, a massive performance boost can be obtained by switching to a numeric solver like [`fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) or [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) (only `fzero` is posted here since it was faster and is part of the basic MATLAB suite):

```
function result = myfunc(mymatrix)

    A = mymatrix*[3;5;-6];
    f = @(t,k) A(k,:)*t + 7;

    N = size(A,1);
    result(N,1) = 0;
    for k = 1:N
        result(k) = fzero(@(t) f(t,k),0);
    end

end
```

On my machine, this function runs in 0.02-ish seconds, 30 times faster than the symbolic approach.